# Symfony2 form validation - this value is not valid

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I got a form in Symfony but it won't validate and I don't know why.

From UserBundle/Entity/Task.php

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project\TaskBundle\Entity\Task", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="project_users_tasks")
 * 
 */
protected $tasks;
```

From UserBundle/Form/CreateUserFormType.php which is my formbuilder:

```
 $builder->add('tasks', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'TaskBundle:Task',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
                ->andWhere('b.owner = :owner')
                ->setParameter('owner', $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser())
                ->addOrderBy('b.updated', 'ASC');
            },
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false
            ));
```

The post request in my browser:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary6IBT2Ycy78N9AI7u
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="createUser[tasks][]"

14
```

The result I get for the form is an error concerning the tasks:
"This value is not valid"

I got no other validation what so ever. So why can't the task 14(which is clean the dishes for example) be assigned to my user? I mean the id of the task should work or not?

**Edit:**
Symfony doesn't seem to recognize the data, that's why. A print_r of $form->getData();

```
[tasks:protected] => Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object
        (
            [_elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

But how can that be? I can see that my browser is posting the data.

Comment: Do you have Branch with id=14 when you submit the form?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo there. It's actually a task but yes, I have a task with id=14 when I submit the form.

Comment: hm.. is current user (on form show and on form submit action) an owner of the task with id=14

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, there are two brackets too much in your submitted field name: `createUser[tasks][]` should be `createUser[tasks]`, since the entity field is a collapsed, single-valued entity field.

Also try to debug Symfony's request object. `var_dump($request->request->get('createUser'))` should return something like

```
array(
    'tasks' => 14,
)
```

If, on the other hand, you really *want* to submit *one or more* tasks, set the "multiple" option on the entity field to `true`. Then the request data should be something like

```
array(
    'tasks' => array(
        0 => 14,
    )
)
```

Comment: how can we check where it fails? Is there some logs for the form validations?